# Find next smallest number

Tags: excel, numbers

I have equipment list:

```
    A   B
1   1   Motor
2   2   Flange
3   3   Pipe
4   4   Pump
5   5   Bolt
6   6   Nut
7   7   Washer
```

The list names are coming from another function and if some of the equipment is not listed I need to reorganize numbering automatically with excel function (no macro). For example customer needs only Motor, Pipe and Bolt. Then the list should look like:

```
         A           B
1        1           Motor
2        (empty)     (empty)
3        2           Pipe
4        (empty)     (empty)
5        3           Bolt
6        (empty)     (empty)
7        (empty)     (empty)
```

Values in cells B are already working. So if value in cell B2 is (empty) “” in corresponding A2 I need it to be empty too. But if in cell B2 is word motor or any number I need it to pick the next available number from the top. Also numbering can be started from cell A5, depending on the list of equipment. I have tried to use IF function but was not able to get the working one. Hopefully I have described it clearly. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. The formula in A1 is

`=IF(B1="","",COUNTIFS(B1:$B$1,"<>"&""))`

You are basically counting non-empty cells in column B up to the current row and only showing the count in rows where the non-empty cells are.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This one is otherwise working good. However if like in my case B1 is referring to the cell where is IF function, the numbering goes for some reason wrong. I have tried this function where B1 is just typed text and not an IF function and everything works fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: This is because Excel doesn't consider a cell with a formula empty in this case. Please try this one:

Comment: =IF(B1="","",COUNTIFS(B1:$I$6,"="&"*?"))

Comment: sorry, that should be =IF(B1="","",COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,"="&"*?"))

Comment: Thank you million times! You saved my day! Hail the Mladen Savic! Making an automated price list. Now my tool is more advanced!